# Zip library to read zip headers

Tags: c++, zip

Hi Guys I need a zip library with which I will be able to validate the file. I would like to read the crc from the zip header using this library and compare it with my own calculated crc. Could you suggest me any??

Answer (score 0):

The format of zip files is very simple, so you don't really need a library to read them. You can find the [complete specification for zip files here](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). It should take you no more than an hour to write some code to locate the zip 'local file header' of interest in the archive and extract the CRC32.

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time I've used this:

http://zziplib.sourceforge.net/

But nowadays I use my own code, as others suggest.

Answer (score -1):

zlib should be enough. Take a look here: http://zlib.net/manual.html#Checksum

Comment: zlib, confusingly, does not read zip libraries. Rather, it implements the deflate compression algorithm. It also has some helper functions for creating gzip streams (which again are different from zip). You are right though that zlib contains a function to calculate CRC32, but that's not what Alex asked for.

Comment: zlib contains a small contribution called minizip (in the contrib folder) It can be compiled and used to achieve this